# How to obtain an Nginx build for windows with Stream options enabled

Tags: nginx

I need an Nginx build for windows that has the following option enabled.

> --with-stream
>
> --with-stream_ssl_preread_module

Unfortunately I don't have the ability to compile the code.
**How can I obtain a build that has these options already enabled?**

Comment: You can take an [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/download.html#windows) bundle. It has all the you mentioned (and many other).